# Array with size from user input

Tags: arrays, input, go

I have this bit of code:

```
fmt.Scanf("%dx%d", &sizex, &sizey)  
var grid [sizex][sizey]int
```

I'm currently getting the "non-constant array bound sizex" error. How can I create array with dimensions chosen by user? Of course, I don't want to modify its size later, but I obviously can't use constants.

Comment: An array's size must be a constant. You have to use a slice.

Comment: @JimB, no, you misunderstood. I don't want to change the size of an array; I just want to create one with size chosen by user

Comment: Yes, I understand. It doesn't matter if you want to change the size or not, the value must be a [constant value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants).

Comment: JimB is not saying "change the size" he's noting the difference between  the size being available at the time you compile the application vs input at runtime. As far as the runtimes concerned you are "changing the size" when the application executes that line of code.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [The Go Blog - Arrays, slices (and strings)](https://blog.golang.org/slices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for;

```
grid := make([][]int, sizex)
for i := 0; i < len(grid) i++ {
     grid[i] = make([]int, sizey)
}
```

This is sort of like using the `new` keyword in C++ verse regular "on the stack" allocation. To use the declaration in your question the size args would have to be values known at compile time.

In the example above `make` only applies to the first dimension, giving me an array of `[]int` arrays, however, none of those arrays have been initialized so I have to iterate over grid and call make with the `sizey` to get the second dimension allocated.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! I'll mark as accepted as soon as possible